# How to apply function to dataframe in place

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, vectorization

Is there a way I could use a scipy function like [`norm.cdf`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) **in place** on a `numpy.array` (or `pandas.DataFrame`), using a variant of `numpy.apply`, [`numpy.apply_along_axs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html), etc?

---

The background is, I have a table of z-score values that I would like to convert to CDF values of the norm distribution. I'm currently using [`norm.cdf`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) from `scipy` for this.

I'm currently manipulating a dataframe that has non-numeric values.

```
      Name      Val1      Val2      Val3      Val4 
0        A -1.540369 -0.077779  0.979606 -0.667112   
1        B -0.787154  0.048412  0.775444 -0.510904   
2        C -0.477234  0.414388  1.250544 -0.411658   
3        D -1.430851  0.258759  1.247752 -0.883293   
4        E -0.360181  0.485465  1.123589 -0.379157
```

(Making the `Name` variable an index is a solution, but in my actual dataset, the names are not alphabetical characters.)

To modify only the numeric data, I'm using [`df._get_numeric_data()`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/pandas.DataFrame._data.get_numeric_data) a private function that returns a dataframe containing a dataframe's numeric data. However, there is no `set` function. Hence, if I call

```
norm.cdf(df._get_numeric_data)
```

this won't change `df`'s original data.

I'm trying to circumvent this by applying `norm.cdf` to the numeric dataframe **inplace**, so this changes my original dataset.

Comment: You can get the numeric columns from the index of `_get_numeric_data` the key thing though is that you have to assign back to the df columns that you want to overwrite so you could do something like `for col in df._get_numeric_data.index:  df[col] = norm.cdf(df[col])` or similar

Answer (score 6):

I think I would prefer [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) over `_get_numeric_data`:

```
In [11]: df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
Out[11]:
       Val1      Val2      Val3      Val4
0 -1.540369 -0.077779  0.979606 -0.667112
1 -0.787154  0.048412  0.775444 -0.510904
2 -0.477234  0.414388  1.250544 -0.411658
3 -1.430851  0.258759  1.247752 -0.883293
4 -0.360181  0.485465  1.123589 -0.379157
```

Although apply doesn't offer an inplace, you could do something like the following (which I would argue was more explicit anyway):

```
num_df = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
df[num_df.columns] = norm.cdf(num_df.values)
```

Comment: You're right, I think `select_dtypes` is the more kosher way to get the numeric data. I think @EdChum's answer was hinting at this answer as well. It would be nice if there were an `inplace=True` option though.

Comment: @hlin117 ah yes, I missed that, doing it column-wise *may* be better option as you avoid possibly upcasting the dtype (e.g. from int to float), depends... probably much of a muchness. :)

Comment: @hlin117 I would also say that inplace is often a little disingenuous in pandas, as even with an inplace argument is passed you can make a copy - and tbh/imo that's no big deal and makes everything easier to reason about/more explicit. If you want to do inplace stuff, do it with numpy *then* use pandas...

Comment: Good point about numpy and inplace operations. But my original dataset comes best as a dataframe (since each column has a column name). And I'd like to minimize the amount of memory used as possible.

Comment: @hlin117 the issue is pandas copies if you mutate the data, the only way you could hope this would work inplace was if norm.cdf worked inplace - which I don't think it does, *and* you pass it just the float or just the int values and modify them - however that last part working is really an implementation detail (pandas doesn't guarantee it).